# Is it possible to add a model-agnostic scope to Rails ORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the following query quite often, to return objects with a certain attribute present:

```
User.where("name is NOT NULL and name != ''")
```

Is it possible to make this into a globally usable scope? E.g

```
Car.find_all_with_present(:rear_view_mirror)
House.find_all_with_present(:front_yard)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a `default_scope`?

Comment: No, not if you mean it by [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope).

Answer (score 3):

Create a module with this global scope and then include it in the Active Record. Something like this should do the work:

```
module GlobalScopes
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def self.find_all_with_present(field)
        scoped.where("#{field} IS NOT NULL AND #{field} != ''")
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, GlobalScopes)
```

Comment: I cannot get it to work. Most probably because I'm such a noob. But it sure looks right!